# Facebook Login dialog disappears after clicking on Facebook sign in button

Tags: android, facebook

I have problem with Facebook sign in button. I have implemented all the steps in this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/, and it works correctly on my `Kitkat` phone, but when i try it on `Oreo` phone, the dialog for choosing Facebook account disappears immediately after clicking on Sign in button and i do not understand why. Facebook app exists on the two phones.

I got these lines in `Logcat` when i clicked Sign in button

```
2019-12-08 14:49:39.002 8929-8929/com.example.testforgooglesignin W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 8

2019-12-08 14:49:39.015 8929-8929/com.example.testforgooglesignin W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection

2019-12-08 14:49:39.020 8929-8929/com.example.testforgooglesignin W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

2019-12-08 14:49:39.303 8929-8929/com.example.testforgooglesignin V/ActivityThread: Finishing stop of ActivityRecord{5207081 token=android.os.BinderProxy@eb8182a {com.example.testforgooglesignin/com.example.testforgooglesignin.MainActivity}}

2019-12-08 14:49:44.099 8929-8929/com.example.testforgooglesignin V/ActivityThread: Handle window ActivityRecord{5207081 token=android.os.BinderProxy@eb8182a {com.example.testforgooglesignin/com.example.testforgooglesignin.MainActivity}} visibility: false
```

this is the code in `Manifest`

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

can anyone give me help?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I solved this problem by adding `privacy policy` to Facebook application and making the state of application to be production.

Comment: Can you add some code to see or logcat messages when the problem comes?

Comment: The post is edited

Answer (score 0):

Since the Facebook app is installed on your device and you followed the tutorial link mentioned in your post, it looks like you have enabled Single Sign On. You can try setting login behavior of the login button as follows

```
LoginBehavior mLoginBehavior =LoginBehavior.DIALOG_ONLY;
mLoginButton.setLoginBehavior(mLoginBehavior);
```

This will avoid SSO and force dialog login.

Comment: okay it works but the behavior is not as in `Kitkat` phone, i  do not need this behavior, i need the login dialog to be open in my application

Comment: The same problem appears again, the dialog disappears immediately after clicking on Sign in button on `Lollipop` phones and higher, it only works on `Kitkat`

Comment: The updated answer will allow you to open the web dialog and login. The problem you are facing is because of SSO. You can also experiment with other options of LoginBehavior and see what works for you.

Comment: Thank you but it also does not work, should Facebook app be in production or in development state?

Comment: I solved it by adding privacy policy and making the state of application to be production. Thank you for your help

Comment: Please edit your post to mention how you solved it.